# R: removing objects in a for loop

Tags: r

I am new to R language. I wanted to remove all objects in a loop like this:

```
for (name in ls()) rm(name)
```

Unfortunately, I does not work. Could someone explain why? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are removing the variable `name` instead of the object called name. In order to remove the object, you need to use the `list` argument of `rm`.

```
# creating variable name
name <- ls()[1]
# removing variable name
rm(name)
# creating variable name
name <- ls()[1]
# removing object called name
rm(list=name)
```

So your loop should look like

```
for (name in ls()) rm(list = name)
```

However, that will leave an object called `name` in your global environment. It is better to just use @Andrie's answer

```
rm(list = ls())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rm()` with the list argument.  Try this:

```
rm(list = ls())
```